# Can Coco/R turn a parsed file into bytecode?

Tags: delphi, compiler-construction, cocor

I want to write a simple compiler for educational purposes in Delphi. I have read about Coco/R and found this implementation for Delphi: http://code.google.com/p/dcocor/ . From what I have read, this is a parser for the Delphi 2009 syntax.

What would I have to do to turn the parsed file into a bytecode? Can Coco/R do this?

I know about scripting languages like FastScript or DWS, but I'd like to try and write my own for my own purposes.

Please give me some advice or clarify things a little.

Comment: Have you read the Coco/R manual?  I'd say to start there.  http://ssw.jku.at/Coco/Doc/UserManual.pdf

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What would I have to do to turn the parsed file into a bytecode?

First, decide what kind of bytecode would you like to have: JVM? LLVM? MSIL? Inventing your own?

> Can Coco/R do this?

Coco/R is a parser generator framework, it only generates lexer-parser for a language you define and feed to the generator. Steps after that is your responsibility. Though there might be projects out there that can help generating ast/target code (but I haven't found any for Coco/R ).

Comment: I would like to simply convert my scripts to an executable code - x86 EXE are perfectly fine. I found a LLVM parser for Delphi (http://code.google.com/p/llvm-pascal/), but it doesn't seem to generate bytecode. Am I missing something?

Comment: What this answer is telling you is that you will need to write your own code generator.

Comment: @Pateman: that project is a Pascal compiler with LLVM backend, not an arbitrary script to executable/bytecode. No such thing exists however. Read Coco/R documentation if you want to use it, what the parser generates, and after deciding your target arch, map what the parser generates to your target arch native language (i.e. x86 asm, llvm ir, etc.)

Comment: @LeleDumbo Oh, so you're saying that I can "bind" the project to LLVM? Will I be able to generate bytecode that way? Sorry if I'm being ignorant right now, but it's all confusing to me, that's why I asked for clarification.

Comment: @Pateman You can take what Coco/R spits out (an AST I assume) and run with it, for instance generate LLVM IR code from it. If you have compiled the programs to LLVM IR, you'll need a way to tell the set of libraries that are LLVM that they shall take this code, optimize it, and pass it to its x86 backend to generate machine code.

Comment: More or less like what @delnan said. LLVM IR could be compiled to its own bitcode (yep, it's bitcode because it's encoded in bits instead of bytes) format, which could be executed with its JIT execution engine, or compiled to native architecture format (still in assembly) and later, to native executable.

Comment: I see... It's more complicated than I thought.

Comment: Have you ever learned compiler construction anyway? The process is actually trivial for any compiler/interpreter, aside from the compiler specific features. input -> lexer -> parser -> ast -> code generator -> output